# error with import Export wizard sql-server

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL-server 2012. I have a large excel file about 200 MB in size. I normally Import data from excel file to sqlserver by using sql-server management studio (by selecting database->Tasks->Import data) then selecting microsoft excel as datasource.

I have noticed several times whenever i use any excel file more than 100MB I gets this error

### TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

The operation could not be completed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
Unexpected error from external database driver (ڟ珉⒀珉Ɇ 䠠⁖). (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)
```

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

here are technical details which i don't even know what it is

===================================

===================================

Unexpected error from external database driver (ڟ珉⒀珉Ɇ 䠠⁖). (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)

---

Program Location:

```
 at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.GetOpenedConnection(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String connEntryName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step1.OnLeavePage(LeavePageEventArgs e)
```

is there any other way to import data or sugession of any application that can do data insert for me

Comment: did you split the excel file in the multiple files and try it again.

Comment: It will work once once I split files under 100MB, but i have more than 500 files like this over 200MB..is there any software available that can split files...because opening the file and copy-pasting data to another excel sheet also takes lot of time..and most of the times hangs Excel aswell..

Comment: I have use powershell in past for 1 or 2 files.. 500 is large number for file. did you try bulk insert with tsql

Comment: thanks hiten,,I've use it before still I get error. now the trouble for me is I have to open manually each file and split into 2...normally whenever excel file is under 100 MB I do net get any error

Answer (score 0):

Another way to import the data is to save the Excel file as a Comma Separated Values (.csv) format. Then import the .csv file. This simplifies the import process and allows you to get past any Excel specific issues.